# Under what circumstances should a unicode program like this not run?

Tags: java, unicode, bluej

Here is the java code in my bluej ide

```
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0055\u004e\u0049
\u007b
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d\u0020\u0061\u0029
\u007b
\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u0028\u0022\u0048\u0031\u0022\u0029\u003b
\u007d
\u007d
```

Which if passed through `native2ascii -reverse` is:

```
public class UNI
{
public static void main(String[] a)
{
System.out.print("H1");
}
}
```

Yesterday, I was having problems with spaces. Today it seems to run.
Can anyone tell under what circumstances there should be a problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "problem with spaces"?

Comment: What problems, specifically? And who the heck writes code as a bunch of Unicode escapes?

Comment: Under no circumstances should a program like that run. I know that it does, but that is no excuse.

Comment: Yesterday, I wrote this same program, but it did not compile until I gave spaces at the beginning of the program.

Comment: Do you have the error message you received when it did not compile?  Very hard to tell you what is wrong based on "I got an error message yesterday"...

Comment: I don't remember the error. It was a compile time error, not a run-time error. The problem got solved when I gave a space before public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling and running your provided code (with no spurious whitespace) shows no problems:

```
$ cat UNI.java
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0063\u006c\u0061\u0073\u0073\u0020\u0055\u004e\u0049
\u007b
\u0070\u0075\u0062\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0073\u0074\u0061\u0074\u0069\u0063\u0020\u0076\u006f\u0069\u0064\u0020\u006d\u0061\u0069\u006e\u0028\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u005b\u005d\u0020\u0061\u0029
\u007b
\u0053\u0079\u0073\u0074\u0065\u006d\u002e\u006f\u0075\u0074\u002e\u0070\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0074\u0028\u0022\u0048\u0031\u0022\u0029\u003b
\u007d
\u007d

$ javac UNI.java

$ java UNI
H1
```

Java largely ignores whitespace, so "[adding] spaces at the beginning of the file" should have no effect.  Whatever problem you had previously was most likely confusion due to trying to work with source code written as Unicode escapes.  You'll have a much easier time writing compilable code if you stick to the "real" characters...